# Convert a column in dataframe into a factor error

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change the *Strategy* column into a factor variable, and used the following:

```
jan17dat[,"Strategy"] <- as.factor(jan17dat[,"Strategy"])
```

but got this error.

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Tried to order the column strategy as follows;

```
jan17dat<-jan17dat[order(jan17dat$Strategy)]
```

But got this error.

```
Error: Column indexes must be at most 30 if positive, not 51, 68, 90, 100, 103, 115, 129, 158, 173, 183, 194, 227, 319, 333, 367, 389, 454, 463, 493,
```

This is part of my data:

```
Strategy    Last trade   P&L    Age
KBand       44939.55     20
boll        84550.86     19
te          84550.86     19
RSI         126576.81    130
bh          6321355.26   17363
will        39294.69     17
mae         0            0
ichi        -12876.14    26
cmci        76046.52     16
tas         63197.1      11
KBand       -33729.9     6
ichi        6698.04      4
MACD        6674.36      5
ad          -26684.6     2
will        -33332.65    7
boll        -33299.6     40
te          -33299.6     40
mae         0            0
```

Comment: Have you tried `jan17dat$Strategy <- as.factor(jan17dat$Strategy)`?

Comment: You can use `dput(jan17dat)` to print your data. Then someone can reproduce your question.

Comment: Thank You.  just did as you suggested and it works.  any idea why this works vs the other?

Answer (score 2):

Both options should work, see example:

```
d1 <- mtcars[, 1:3]
str(d1)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...

d1[, "cyl"] <- as.factor(d1[, "cyl"])
str(d1)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...

d2 <- mtcars[, 1:3]
str(d2)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...

d2$cyl <- as.factor(d2$cyl)
str(d2)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...

identical(d1, d2)
# [1] TRUE
```